# How to configure Json Settings object in Datapower

Tags: ibm-datapower

I configured a Json settings object for the domain in order to increase the maximum payload size of responses allowed.  I'm assuming I need to configure my mpgw service to use this json settings object, because I'm assuming it doesn't automatically apply the setting to every service in the domain just because I created the object.  But where do I configure my service or requests to use this json settings object that exists in the domain?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you add the Json Settings object to the service's XML Manager configuration.